# Backup bash script explain

Tags: bash

I have some problem because my friends send me a script to backup my folders when any files will change. However I don't understand bash scripts. Can someone explain me every line of this code what they do?

```
#!/bin/bash

SOURCE="/var/www/my_web/load/"
BACKUP="/home/your_user/load/"
LBACKUP="/home/your_user/load/latest-full/"

DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%T)

DESTINATION="$BACKUP"/"$DATE"-diff/

rsync -av --compare-dest="$LBACKUP" "$SOURCE" "$DESTINATION"

cd "$DESTINATION"
find . -depth -type d -empty -delete
```

Regards,
Sebastian

Comment: Run `man bash`, `man date`, `man rsync`, `man find`, and `help cd` in a bash shell.

Comment: Have you tried running any of these commands in a shell to see what you get?

Comment: Yes, but i dont understand everything that why i writing to you gays! I dont wanna learn bash, only know exacly what this script do on every line of code. I have problem to understand DESTINATION line and FIND line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Bash script will:

1. Set the source directory (`SOURCE`).
2. Set the destination backup directory (`BACKUP`).
3. Set the destination directory for latest full backup (`LBACKUP`).
4. Get the current system date in `Y-m-d-Time` format (`DATE`).
5. Sets the destination directory as `BACKUP`+`/`+`DATE`+`-diff`.
6. Rsync/copy the files from the `SOURCE` to the `DESTINATION` folder by comparing the files from `LBACKUP` directory.
7. Enters the destination folder (`cd "$DESTINATION"`).
8. Removes any empty folders (`find`).

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help!